# Where should I set the TLS Security Protocol in a windows server?

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-services, tls1.2

Is there a specific method in a windows service where I should explicitly set the TLS 1.2 security protocol?

ie. is there a specific event on startup that is best to do this so it is globally set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. My guess would be

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: where in the startup process?  is there a startup event in the service lifecycle that is best to put this in.